# jQuery - insertBefore() for raw text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery 1.11.2 and jQuery-migrate 1.2.1. Here is the simple example of what I'm trying to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/bek3wrug/

I want to insert some text (not fully-wrapped into HTML tag) before some element on page, and jQuery only inserts the part that is wrapped inside HTML tag.
I cannot use `prepend()` as I don't want to insert it **inside** some element, I need to insert it **before**.

Is there a way to make jQuery insert all the text, not only wrapped into HTML tags?

Comment: With 2k reputation you should already know, that a question should contain all infos necessary for us to reproduce the problem **in the question itself** and not only a link to a 3rd-party resource.

Comment: using jquery before() should do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it contains textNode you need to use [`jQuery.parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) method, which generates an array of nodes. Otherways it will be interpreted as a selector and nothing would happen since nothing get selected using the string.

```
$($.parseHTML("Raw text to insert. <span>Text inside span to insert. </span>")).insertBefore("#mySpan")
```

Refer:  [Creating new elements using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements).

```js
$($.parseHTML("Raw text to insert. <span>Text inside span to insert. </span>")).insertBefore("#mySpan")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <span id="mySpan">Original text</span>
</div>
```

---

Or use [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method.

```
$("#mySpan").before("Raw text to insert. <span>Text inside span to insert. </span>")
```

```js
$("#mySpan").before("Raw text to insert. <span>Text inside span to insert. </span>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <span id="mySpan">Original text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `before`:

```
$("#mySpan").before("Raw text to insert. <span>Text inside span to insert. </span>")
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
$("#mySpan").before("Raw text to insert. <span>Text inside span to insert. </span>")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
<span id="mySpan">Original text</span>
</div>
```